# Hello World example with flask and react

Tags: reactjs, rest, flask, flask-restful

I have setup a `flask` rest API as so:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
   return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Now, I have also setup a react front-end. All I want to do is make a `GET` request to my `flask` rest API and `console.log` the resulting string `Hello World". I had some`CORS`issues so I added the line`CORS(app)`, however I am still having some trouble.

My fetch request looks as so...

```
componentDidMount() {

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(result=>result)
      .then(item=>console.log(item))
      .catch(e=>{
        console.log(e);
        return e;
      })
}
```

The result I get back is the following...

```
Response { type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:5000/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, bodyUsed: false } App.js:24
```

There is no sign of my `Hello World` string. I also noticed that my server is making an `OPTIONS` request...

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2018 14:13:54] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2018 14:13:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I decided that this might be do to my `application/json` in the headers. So I removed it...

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
  method: 'GET',
})
  .then(result=>result)
  .then(item=>console.log(item))
  .catch(e=>{
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  })
```

The `OPTIONS` request disappeared, however my response is still the same.

I cannot seem to get the string to my front-end. I have no idea what my issue might be anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning a string from your Flask route, you can use [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/) to return a Response object:

```
return jsonify({"data": "Hello World"})
```

Then in React, you can call the [`json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) method on your response to get a JavaScript object containing your data:

```
.then(result=>result.json())  // instead of .then(result=>result)
```

You should then see the following logged to the console:

```
{data: "Hello World"}
```

---